# Angular.js - Wrapper directive around existing select directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've made a custom select dropdown using some markup, css and a regular select element without any javascript, but I would like to make this an angularjs directive so I don't have to keep repeating the boilerplate html in my application. Here's an example of the markup used (with no angularjs stuff yet)

```
<div class="select">
  <select name="mySelect">
    <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Value 3</option>
  </select>
  <span class="select-value">Value 1</span>
  <span class="select-arrow"><i></i></span>
</div>
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
<my-select ng-model="mySelect" ng-options="opt.val as opt.label for opt in options">
```

similar to how I would with the built in select directive. Is there an easy way to wrap or extend the select directive while keeping it's features?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried making a directive with an ng-select in its template?

Comment: I've thought about it, but I'm not sure if there would be issues with the data binding with the ng-options. I'll give it a shot though

Comment: I just gave it a shot now, and the only options i can see is to use string manipulation in the template or to lock the ng-options to only work with a specified data type, which i'd prefer not to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Using a decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator) will allow you to modify a directive, even a built-in one. For example:

```js
angular.module('directiveDecoration', [])
    .config(['$provide', Decorate]);

function Decorate($provide) {

  //decorate angular's built-in select directive
  $provide.decorator('selectDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0],
      link = directive.link;

    //directive.templateUrl = "test/something.tpl.html";

    directive.compile = function() {
      return function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        link.apply(this, arguments);

        //do more  stuff here...
      }
    };

    return $delegate;
  }]);
}
```